# How much high is the amplitude of stator-MMF of 3-phase 2-spp integral slot winding type machine as compared to 3-phase1-spp machine of same type?

Tags: motor, induction-motor, electrical, electromagnetic, stator

Details:
No. of POLES=2; i.e 1-pole pair
SPP= slots per pole per phase
In my case,
amplitude of MMF of 3-phase 1-spp machine= 0.75;

1. Then what should be the amplitude of MMF for 2-spp machine ?
2. Is it 2x mmf of 1-spp machine?

Answer (score 0):

A machine is usually designed to utilize the materials as effectively as possible. An induction motor rotor of a given diameter and length can be effectively used to produce a certain torque in a two pole machine. If you have an effective design with a certain number of slots and winding configuration for a given machine, the objective for the design of the same machine with a different slot and winding configuration should be to obtain the asme MMF. The number of turns and wire size should be adjusted accordingly.